# Redirecting http to https in Apache2 and my domain build is in var/www/html

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I have uploaded build in var/www/html and ssl is configure and trying to redirect http to https but it is not redirecting. I have checked for .htaccess file but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Include this in htaccess to redirect http to https

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

---

Include this in htaccess to redirect www to non-www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.yourdomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have already added but my .htaccess file is in /var/www/html/ and my apache.conf file is etc/apache2 location to how can i give access to .htaccess file.

Comment: share the snippet of virtualhost(.conf) and .haccess file contents. so that, I can check better

Comment: Response to above comment, also need to remove www

Comment: Thanks for answer, it is working for http to https. when I call it using www then it is redirect not secure mode. Can you please help me to remove www and redirect to https.